# Splitting an aggregate across bounded contexts

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I have an example similar to what is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/microservice-domain-model):

> *An entity’s identity can cross multiple microservices or Bounded*
>   *Contexts.*
>
> The same identity (that is, the same Id value, although perhaps not
>   the same domain entity) can be modeled across multiple Bounded
>   Contexts or microservices. However, that does not imply that the same
>   entity, with the same attributes and logic would be implemented in
>   multiple Bounded Contexts. Instead, entities in each Bounded Context
>   limit their attributes and behaviors to those required in that Bounded
>   Context’s domain.
>
> For instance, the buyer entity might have most of a person’s
>   attributes that are defined in the user entity in the profile or
>   identity microservice, including the identity. But the buyer entity in
>   the ordering microservice might have fewer attributes, because only
>   certain buyer data is related to the order process. The context of
>   each microservice or Bounded Context impacts its domain model.

In my case, I have a `Subscription` model that two different bounded contexts that have their own attributes.

Going a step further, a `Subscription` belongs to an `Agency`, and an `Agency` can only have one (not 0, not many) `Subscriptions`.

So based on this, I've been thinking what the aggregate id will be. As a `Subscription` has a 1-1 mapping with an `Agency`, is it OK to use the same ID as the `Agency`?

I think this makes sense as a `Subscription` doesn't need it's own ID. Even if it did I don't think it would be returned to the user, the user can reference it through the owning `Agency` id.

In this bounded context the `Agency` aggregate (or it's attributes) are not relevant so I don't believe they are part of the same aggregate.

To sum up, is it OK for an aggregate to share the ID of another aggregate if it is a 1-1 mapping?

Comment: Clarification questions. If `Subscription` can only be referenced through the owning `Agency`, should it even be considered an `Aggregate`? Is `Agency` as a concept present in both the `Bounded Contexts`, along with `Subscription`? What happens to the `Subscription` when the `Agency` is archived/deleted? Are you using an RDBMS for persistence or a document store? Is the mechanism of using different primary IDs and linking to `Agency` through an `agency_id` attribute an option?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the actual implementation w.r.t. the `Id` really matters.  It should be perfectly fine to share an identifier.

This is somewhat different from "splitting an aggregate across" BCs which is something you most certainly would *not* want to do :)

An aggregate in one BC would be represented either by an id or as a value object in another BC.  Only a single BC should be the *system of record* of any aggregate.